# Hiding the toolbars in iOS 7 using overlay hack

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I've been reading around Stack Overflow and searching on Google for a reliable way to hide the toolbars on iOS 7 as the old scroll trick no longer works.

Based on this: http://mihhaillapushkin.wordpress.com/2014/01/20/stop-navigation-bars-from-appearing-in-iphone-ios7-safari/

I've tried the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <style type="text/css">

            *
            {
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                outline: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            html,
            body
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            div.content
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                bottom: 0px;
                width: 320px;
                height: 480px;
                background: orange;
            }

            #scroller {
                height: 100%;
                -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                overflow: scroll;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
                width: 100%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="default">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            setInterval(function(){

                if((window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) && window.innerHeight != window.outerHeight) {

                    $('#scroller').show();

                } else {

                    $('#scroller').hide();

                }

            }, 1000);

        </script>

        <div class="content">

            <div id="scroller" style="z-index: 100000;position: fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;">
                Scroll up!
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

But scrolling up never actually hides the scrollbars. The `#scroller` is hiding and showing if the toolbars are visible or not, so half of it works, but just not the hiding unless I bounce the content into the toolbar, but if I scroll then the toolbars appear again.

Have I misunderstood the implementation?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide the Safari Address bar you need to add this meta tags

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

The status bar can be hidden in iOS 7.1 and above with this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui”>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, however those top two only work when adding the website to the home screen and I don't want to rely on 7.1.

Comment: As far as I know, when making the website app capable and installing it on the home page is the only way to hide the toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, here is an answer from the author.

I have not dived into your code block, but just to clarify what I've told about in that post.

Firstly, I have shown an example of a game that has adopted an overlay that forces the player to scroll up until the bars go away. After the game detects that bars are no longer visible it locks scrolling until the player triggers navigation bars again, forcing him to go through the loop again.

Secondly, I have revealed a trick that for some reason deactivates navigation bar triggering ONLY for the top part of the screen. The bottom still triggers them as usual, so the the overlay I mentioned earlier is still needed. Thus this is a half-solution for the problem, but it is still better than nothing.

IMHO, the combination of those 2 approaches yields a good-enough solution for games and other applications that need full-screen without the need for scrolling.